# How generics really works as in parameters?

Tags: java, generics, functional-programming

I'm little confused about how the generics works? I'm learning about `function` [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) in java and there I just test `Function` interface and got confused about `compose` method that how the generics is working in `compose` method.

Reading the generics on the java official tutorial website I realize that if we have any generic type in the method return or parameters we have to declare that type in the signature of method as explained below.

Here is the method I read in [official docs tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html).

```
public static <K, V> boolean compare(Pair<K, V> p1, Pair<K, V> p2) {
    return p1.getKey().equals(p2.getKey()) &&
           p1.getValue().equals(p2.getValue());
}
```

Above method have two types, K, V which are declared in the signature after the static keyword as  but when I read java `Function` [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) there is one method called `compose` and the signature of the compose is as

```
default <V> Function<V, R> compose(Function<? super V, ? extends T> before) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(before);
    return (V v) -> apply(before.apply(v));
}
```

**1) The first question** where is the T & R declared? which are being used in the return type and in the parameter. Or my understanding is wrong?

Then I read more in generics tutorials and then I try to understand the concept of `super` and `extends` in generics and [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java) then I test `compose` method more and then confused again about how the `super` and `extends` works in the `compose` method?

```
public static void main(String... args){
    Function<Integer, String> one = (i) -> i.toString();
    Function<String, Integer> two = (i) -> Integer.parseInt(i);
    one.compose(two);
}
```

As above I have declared two Function with lamdas. One is having Integer input and String output the other one is reversed from it.

**2) The second question** is that how `Integer` and `String` are related to `extends` and `super`? There is no relation between `String` and `Integer` class no one is extending each other then how it is working?

I tried my best to explain my question/problem. Let me know what you didn't understand I will try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are `T` and `R` defined?

Remember, `compose` is declared in the `Function` interface. It can not only use generic parameters of its own, but also the type's generic parameters. `R` and `T` are declared in the interface declaration:

```
interface Function<T, R> {
    ...
}
```

What are `? extends` and `? super`?

`?` is wildcard. It means that the generic parameter can be anything. `extends` and `super` give constraints to the wildcard. `? super V` means that whatever `?` is, it must be a superclass of `V` or `V` itself. `? extends T` means that whatever `?` is, it must be a subclass of `T` or `T` itself.

Now let's look at this:

```
Function<Integer, String> one = (i) -> i.toString();
Function<String, Integer> two = (i) -> Integer.parseInt(i);
one.compose(two);
```

From this, we can deduce that `T` is `Integer` and `R` is `String`. What is `V`? `V` must be some type such that the constraints `Function<? super V, ? extends T>` is satisfied.

We can do this by substituting the argument we passed in - `Function<String, Integer>` - to get `String super V` and `Integer extends Integer`.

The second constraint is satisfied already while the first constraint now says that `String` must be a super class of `V` or `String` itself. `String` cannot have subclasses so `V` must be `String`.

Hence, you can write something like:

```
Function<String, String> f = one.compose(two);
```

but not

```
Function<Integer, String> f = one.compose(two);
```

When you compose a `Function<Integer, String>` and a `Function<String, Integer>` you cannot possibly get a `Function<Integer, String>`. If you try to do this, `V` is automatically inferred to be `Integer`. But `String super Integer` is not satisfied, so the compilation fails. See the use of the constraints now? It is to avoid programmers writing things that don't make sense. Another use of the constraints is to allow you to do something like this:

```
Function<A, B> one = ...
Function<C, SubclassOfB> two  = ...
Function<SubclassOfC, B> f = one.compose(two);
```

There is no relationship between `Integer` and `String` in this case, it's all about `V`.

Comment: Thanks a lot understood V must be string but how the `V` determined by the compiler?

Comment: `V` is determined by the compiler. If you write `Function<Integer, String> f = one.compose(two)` then `V` is inferred to be `Integer`, which does not fit the constraints. If you don't include the type, `V` is inferred to be `String`. @UnKnown

Comment: Ok how I can see the inferred code of generic? as bytecode using javap -c.

Comment: @UnKnown I think after compilation the generics just turn into a bunch of casts and all generic parameters just become `Object`. I have never looked at the byte code before but I think you can see some casts.

Answer (score 1):

1) The `compose` function is part of `Interface Function<T,R>`. As you can see in documentation for this interface:

> Type Parameters:
>
> T - the type of the input to the function
>
> R - the type of the result of the function

2) The `super` and `extends` constraints in questions aren't applied to T & R, they're applied to the generic type parameters of a function that you pass in as an argument to the `compose` function.

Basically this means that if you have:

```
Function<ClassA, ClassB> one;
Function<SomeSuperClassOfC, SomeSubclassOfA> two;
```

then it's valid to call

```
Function<ClassC, ClassB> three = one.compose(two)
```

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain from zero;
`interface Function<T, R>` - this is interface with one method, which must be implemented `R apply (T)`;
in Java prior to 8 we must write:

```
Function<Integer, String> one = new Function<Integer, String>() {
    @Override
    public String apply(Integer i) {
        return i.toString();
    }
};
```

now you can use it:

```
String resultApply = one.apply(5);
```

now, I think, you get the idea.